# Importing packages with ReactJs added to a website

Tags: node.js, django, reactjs, npm, axios

I'm not able to import the axios package using ReactJs integrated to my website. It looks like it's only possible when you create a new react app as in my case I dont have a package file only a package-lock one. What's my problem here and what are my options? I have a django back-end.

Comment: did you run `npm init`?

Comment: your question is vague, what do you mean "ReactJs integrated to my website" how do you open project then? if there is no package.json, where are the scripts that run the app in dev?

Comment: I followed the ReactJS documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html